# How do you test that a Ruby method returns the result of another Ruby method?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Let's say I have two methods where one of the methods returns the result of the other method:

```
class SomeClass
  def method_a
    method_b
  end

  def method_b 
    'foobar'
  end
end
```

And I'm trying to test method_a without 'retesting' the logic from method b. To do that, I use something like this:

```
RSpec.describe SomeClass do
  subject { SomeClass.new }

  describe '#method_a' do
    expect(subject).to receive(:method_b)
    subject.method_a
  end
end
```

Usually this works just fine, however, in this case it is important that method a actually returns the result of method b, not just that it gets called. How can I do this? (Perhaps theirs a method for this? Potentially named something like #receive_and_return or #return_value_of_method_call or something along those lines.)

Comment: Mock method B, make it return something outlandish or random, and check A returns the same improbable thing?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why is it important for clients of `method_a` to know how it obtains its result? The whole point of encapsulation and abstraction is that clients do not, should not, and cannot know how stuff is implemented!

Comment: @JörgWMittag That's actually something I've been wrestling with. As far as I can see I have two options: 1) Retest all of the logic for method a every time it's used somewhere else in code or 2) Test that method a was called and keep all of the tests for that methods logic contained to the unit test for method a. Neither one seems like a great option to me but I haven't been able to come up with a third.

Comment: @JörgWMittag What are your thoughts on this? Am I missing an option? I've only just gotten serious about writing tests in the last six months so your opinion would go a long way in setting me on the right track.

Comment: @JoshHadik: `method_a` has some kind of contract that it promises its callers. That contract is *not* "I call `method_b`". That contract is something like "If you pass me a positive real number, I return you the square root of that number". So, you write a couple of tests that pass in a perfect square, 0, a very big number, a very small number, a negative number, and so on, and check that the correct result is returned or an exception is raised. You do *not* assert that `square_root_helper` is called, because nobody cares what methods you call. They only care that you return the correct result

Answer (score 1):

you need rspec-mocks(https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/returning-a-value#specify-a-return-value)

```
RSpec.describe SomeClass do
  describe '#method_a' do
    let(:some_class) { SomeClass.new }
    context 'method_b return foobar' do
      before { allow(some_class).to receive(:method_b).and_return('foobar') }
      it 'will return foobar' do
        allow(some_class).to receive(:method_b).and_return('foobar')
        expect(some_class.method_a).to eq('foobar')
      end
    end
    context 'method_b return barbar' do
      before { allow(some_class).to receive(:method_b).and_return('barbar') }
      it 'will return barbar' do
        expect(some_class.method_a).to eq('barbar')
      end
    end
  end
end
```